# dbset.Remove(entity) not working Got Error at this line

Tags: c#, entity-framework, model-view-controller

**My Delete function is not working.**

```
   public virtual void Delete(T entity)
   {
      dbset.Remove(entity);
   }
```

I have implemented work pattern and repository pattern and entity framework code first. I have code first entities layer, service layer, data context layer and UI layer.My Edit,Update,Add functions are working Fine.But my Delete function is not working.

I am getting this error.
**An exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code.**

Additional information: **Value cannot be null**.
**"Value cannot be null.Parameter name: entity"**

**In my Project controller.My code is like this----**

```
  public class ProjectController : Controller
   {
      private readonly IProjectService _projectService;
      public ProjectController(IProjectService projectService)
   {
      this._projectService = projectService;
   }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
    {
        var projectDetails = _projectService.GetProjectById((int)id);
        if (projectDetails == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("Not Found");
        return View(projectDetails);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Delete(Project project)
    {
        _projectService.DeleteProject(project.ProjectId);
        return RedirectToAction("List","Project");
    }
```

**In my Service Layer , i have all the logic implemented by my controller----**

```
    public class ProjectService : IProjectService
      {
        private readonly IProjectRepository _projectRepository;
        private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
        public ProjectService(IProjectRepository           projectRepository,IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)                  
      {
       this._projectRepository = projectRepository;
       this._unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
   }

   public void DeleteProject(int id)
      {
       var project = _projectRepository.GetById(id);
       _projectRepository.Delete(project);
       _unitOfWork.Commit();
      }
```

**My entity repository base class contain the method which is -------**

```
   public abstract class EntityRepositoryBase<T> where T : class
     {
        private CodeFirstContext _dataContext;
        private readonly IDbSet<T> dbset;
        protected EntityRepositoryBase(IDBFactory databaseFactory)
    {
        DatabaseFactory = databaseFactory;
        dbset = DataContext.Set<T>();
    }

    protected IDBFactory DatabaseFactory
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    protected CodeFirstContext DataContext
    {
        get { return _dataContext ?? (_dataContext = DatabaseFactory.Get()); }
    }

    public virtual void Delete(T entity)
    {
        dbset.Remove(entity);
    }

    public void Delete(Func<T, Boolean> where)
    {
        IEnumerable<T> objects = dbset.Where<T>(where).AsEnumerable();
        foreach (T obj in objects)
        dbset.Remove(obj);
    }
```

**In my IEntityRepository class, the method are-----**

```
  public interface IEntityRepository<T> where T : class
    {
       void Delete(T entity);
       void Delete(Func<T, Boolean> predicate);
     }
```

**My Delete.cshtml file is something like this----**

```
    @model CodeFirstEntities.Models.Project

   @{
      ViewBag.Title = "Delete";
    }

   <h2>Delete</h2>

   <h3>Are you sure you want to delete this?</h3>
   <fieldset>
<legend>Project</legend> 
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ProjectId)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ProjectName)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.DeveloperName)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Address)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Website)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Geolongitude)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Geolatitude)

<div class="display-label">
     @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ProjectName)
</div>
<div class="display-field">
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ProjectName)
</div>

<div class="display-label">
     @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DeveloperName)
</div>
<div class="display-field">
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.DeveloperName)
</div>

<div class="display-label">
     @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Address)
</div>
<div class="display-field">
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Address)
</div>

<div class="display-label">
     @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Website)
</div>
<div class="display-field">
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Website)
</div>

<div class="display-label">
     @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Geolongitude)
</div>
<div class="display-field">
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Geolongitude)
</div>

<div class="display-label">
     @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Geolatitude)
</div>
<div class="display-field">
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Geolatitude)
  </div>
    </fieldset>
     @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
     @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
     <p>
     <input type="submit" value="Delete" /> |
     @Html.ActionLink("List", "Project")
     </p>
       }
```

Comment: Did you checked that here "var project = _projectRepository.GetById(id);" is really not null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking at the markup of just your form, I don't see a place where the project information is specified. Instead, the project information is specified outside of your form. So if you make the following changes, then you will be able to send project information to the server when the Delete button gets pressed.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <p>
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ProjectId)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ProjectName)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.DeveloperName)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Address)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Website)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Geolongitude)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Geolatitude)

        <input type="submit" value="Delete" /> |
        @Html.ActionLink("List", "Project")
    </p>
}
```